# Save command line argument as global variable in C

Tags: c, string, command-line, command

I'm trying to read in two filenames and save them as a global variable in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char infilename;
char outfilename;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){

    strcopy(infilename, argv[1]);


return 0;
}
```

However this does not work. Can someone help me with a really simple problem like this?

Comment: What is your question? Also you are trying to copy a string to a char

Comment: I'd ask what problem you are having, but it is fairly obvious -- a `char` is a character, not a pointer to a sequence of characters, which is what the first parameter of `strcpy()` (mis-spelled here, by the way) should be.

Comment: All that you have is flawed so much beyond, we could fill a basic c++ syntax and logic book to explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: If at all possible, just use a `std::string` so that you don't have to worry about char array sizes, `strcpy`ing, and such.

Comment: @user3124394: Editing your question to clarify it is helpful. Editing your question to address errors that were pointed out in answers is not. If you try a solution and it doesn't work for you, you are best to ask another separate question rather than invalidating the answers that people have invested some time in by changing the existing question.

Comment: Yeah! my answer is all invalidated! Also read the tutorial i posted (and my answer - there is more than just making it a pointer)

Comment: @TheUndeadFish: They added user-namespaces and `string` type to C? Could you provide a link to the new standard.

Comment: @Olaf The original question was tagged with `c` `c++` and had a `using namespace std ` at the top. I removed them because the questions didn't really make sense.

Comment: @Ben:I just had a lok at the text edits, not the tags. This question is nonsense anyway. OP should just learn the language properly and not skip chapters.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to copy a string (`const char *`) to a character (`char`). You need to either declare infilename as a string:

```
char *infilename;
infilename = malloc(...
```

or make a static array:

```
char infilename[NUM_OF_CHARS];
```

Read up on c strings [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson9.html).

Also choose your language, if you are really using `c++` you need to start using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Answer (score 3):

A better way to do it.

```
char infilename[50];
char outfilename[50];

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){

    if(argc == 3)
    {
        strcpy (infilename,argv[1]);
        strcpy (outfilename,argv[2]);
    }
    else
    {
            //do something else
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You need array of char and not only char. A string in C is an array of char. And you must always verify (if(argc == 3) if the user entered the quantity of argument you want, because if it's not the case your applicatin can crash.

Comment: Where did the OP mention a `namespace`?

Comment: @Ben I'd keep `using namespace std;` in the original post, as this answer still pertains to it.

Comment: @PCLuddite But i removed the `c` tag. I think the question is better as it is. I feel like this answer should be edited. Its only the top line that isnt relevant any more.

Comment: @Ben, I changed my answer and removed the comment for the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to work.

These:

```
char infilename;
char outfilename;
```

declare a variables that store a single `char`, not an entire string.

You either need to make those `char` arrays:

```
char infilename[MAX_PATH];
char outfilename[MAX_PATH];
```

or pointers that you plan to initialize with `malloc`ed memory. You have to pick which one you mean.

P.s. there's no function called `strcopy`, it's `strcpy`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to allocate any memory, the command-line argument string is valid for the life of the program, so a `const char* const` should work.

Comment: @Dai If they want to *copy* the string (like in the question), then they need to allocate memory for that. But otherwise, yeah, simple assignment would work.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you made your global variables single characters not an array of characters which is needed for a string.
Assuming you don't want to change the contents of the string then the easiest thing is to simply set a global to point to the same string rather than copying it. Because the program will end when main returns there is no worry about the parameters argv going out of scope.
Note you would have to worry about this if you create a new thread and terminate the thread running main without terminating the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char* gInFilenamePtr;
static char* gOutFilenamePtr;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if( argc > 2 )
    {
        gInFilenamePtr = argv[1];
        gOutFilenamePtr = argv[2];
    }

    return 0;
}
```